# Is JWT authentication possible to run with Mono?

Tags: .net, oauth, mono, jwt, katana

Using [this reference material](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx) on JWT authentication for Katana/OWIN application, I could successfully implement authentication on my service. 
Now I am trying to build and run it under Mono (Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3).

I could successfully build the project code using xbuild, but during execution it fails with following exception -

```
Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.BinarySecretSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I am getting same error while running my application with Mono on Windows as well as Mono on Linux.
I am now clueless how to go about this error. I have been looking for references to this error on SO and else where, but I am not able to find concrete answer anywhere. 
I also came across this [Mono class status page](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.IdentityModel) where I see this class is marked as -

> [image]Missing: we need it

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but please help me understand what does this mean. 
Does it mean that currently there is no Mono implementation available for this class in the given assembly.
If so, what are other alternatives? Any suggestions.

PS: I see similar error posted on SO in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860988/system-identitymodel-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-b77a5c561) but for Android profile. The question remains un-answered.

Comment: At the build time, I also get this warning -         CSC:  warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference `System.IdentityModel.
Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' m
atches assembly `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.20622.1351, Cultur
e=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. You may need to supply runtime poli
cy